# Drawing custom shapes in WPF

Tags: wpf, drawing, geometry, shapes

I am using WPF and created a custom shape.  I read that we can simply override the DefiningGeometry function to draw our shape.. But it does not work for me and I do not understand.  It works for me only when I do it int OnRender().  Why?

This will work:

```
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return Geometry.Empty; }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)        
    {
        FormattedText ft = new FormattedText
           (Text, new CultureInfo("ru-ru"),
           FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
           new Typeface(
              new FontFamily("Arial"),
              FontStyles.Normal,
              FontWeights.Regular,
              new FontStretch()),
           TextHeight,
           new SolidColorBrush(TextColor));

        drawingContext.DrawText
           (ft, new Point(X, Y));
    }
```

But this will not work:

```
    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get {
            FormattedText ft = new FormattedText
           (Text, new CultureInfo("ru-ru"),
           FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
           new Typeface(
              new FontFamily("Arial"),
              FontStyles.Normal,
              FontWeights.Regular,
              new FontStretch()),
           TextHeight,
           new SolidColorBrush(TextColor));

            GeometryGroup group = new GeometryGroup();
            group.Children.Add(ft.BuildGeometry(new Point(X,Y)));

            return group;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)        
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second code should work. You thought it did not work just because the `Stroke` and `Fill` are transparent. You have to intialize them to some explicitly visible brush like this:

```
//the constructor of your own shape
public MyShape(){
   Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
   Fill = Brushes.Red;
}
```

The first code works maybe because the `DrawText` method gets the default ForegroundBrush info from the `FormattedText` to draw the text, I think that default brush should not be transparent. So you can see the drawn text.